# How to show a preview of screen saver inside WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, screensaver

I want to be able to show a preview of a screen saver inside WPF window. (using a container or control or ...) I know that Windows itself passes "/p" argument to the screen saver to get a preview. But how can I show that preview inside my WPF application? Should I get a handle of it and change its parent to my container o control? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Windows.Forms interop, because screen savers expect windows handles (HWND) and in WPF, only top-level windows have them.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="So18547663WpfScreenSaverPreview.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
        Title="Screen Saver Preview" Height="350" Width="525"
        Loaded="MainWindow_OnLoaded" Closed="MainWindow_OnClosed"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="8">
        <TextBlock Text="Preview"/>
        <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="host" Width="320" Height="240">
            <forms:Control Width="320" Height="240"/>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;

namespace So18547663WpfScreenSaverPreview
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        private Process saver;

        public MainWindow ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainWindow_OnLoaded (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            saver = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo {
                FileName = "Bubbles.scr",
                Arguments = "/p " + host.Child.Handle,
                UseShellExecute = false,
            });
        }

        private void MainWindow_OnClosed (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Optional. Screen savers should close themselves
            // when the parent window is destroyed.
            saver.Kill();
        }
    }
}
```

**Assembly references**

- `WindowsFormsIntegration`
- `System.Windows.Forms`

**Related links**

- [Walkthrough: Hosting a Windows Forms Control in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761.aspx)
- [Creating a Screen Saver with C#](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/screensaver/screensaver.html) (describes command line arguments)

Comment: Updated code, now less code-behind. `Windows.Forms.Control` is created in XAML. It's the first time I've used Windows Forms interop; looks like the instruction on MSDN complicates things a bit.

Comment: saver.Kill(); is necessary! In my test it didn't close itself.

Comment: How can I load another screen saver in the host? I tried:`if(saver != null && saver.HasExited == false)
                saver.Kill();
            saver = new Process();
            saver = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = (comboScreenSavers.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Tag.ToString(),
                Arguments = "/p " + hostScreenSaver.Child.Handle,
                UseShellExecute = false,
            });` But It's a mess ...

Comment: If I understodd you correctly, you want to avoid killing the process? A screen saver creates a child window inside your control. You can try sending WM_CLOSE message to it. Not sure the screen saver will respond to it, but it's worth trying.

Comment: No, I have a window just like Windows' screen saver settings. When the user selects a screen saver from the comboBox, the formshost control should show the selected screen saver's preview. The problem is, after the first time I load a preview into the host control, if I try to preview another screen saver, they get mixed up and the host control flashes rapidly and show both previews together and repeatedly! How can I cancel the current one and load another preview?

Comment: Killing the process should work in any case. I have no idea why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks. It worked! I had some misunderstandings about pages life cycle ... I shouldn't have checked if(saver != null) for killing the process. Just checked if it was the first initialization.

Comment: How can I make forms:Control auto resizable? setting margins didn't work?

Comment: I have no idea as I have zero experience with WPF-WinForms interop. You should post a separate question if you can't find a way to do it.