# Is there a way of finding the currently active screen saver in Windows through either C# code or the command prompt?

Tags: c#, windows, command-line-interface, screensaver

I want to check that the screensaver is disabled in my C# application.

It would be great if there was a way of doing this through C# (as I want to check this for a C# application) but I think that it might be more likely that the command line can return the screensaver status.

Comment: [This](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17067/Controlling-The-Screen-Saver-With-C) worked for Windows XP. I have no idea if it will work for Windows Vista, 7, 8 or 10, and I think it probably won't, but it may be a  starting point for some research. Edit: Just noticed it does not tell you what screensaver is set though, sorry :(

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18547663/2263584) too.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfow search for SPI_GETSCREENSAVEACTIVE & note the linked KB

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks, this contains what I need. Btw, how would I use this method (SystemParametersInfoW ) in C#? It's a c++ method.

Answer (score 0):

As @AlexK. shared document, you can find a sample usage. It may help you to solve your problem.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36590/Programmatically-Turning-on-the-Screen-Saver